# Looping through java recursive references

Tags: java, loops, recursion, linked-list

I was writing a simple linked list implementation and the corresponding Trigger class like this:

```
  public class Trigger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      LinkedList lin = new LinkedList();
      lin.add(3);
      lin.add(4);
      lin.add(5);
      lin.display();
    }
  }


 public class LinkedList {
      Item startItem;

      LinkedList() {
      startItem = new Item();
    }  

    public void add(Integer newValue) {
      if(startItem.value == null) {
        startItem.value = newValue;
        return;
      }

    Item tempItem = new Item();
    tempItem.value = newValue;

    while(startItem.next != null) {
     startItem = startItem.next;
    }

    startItem.next = tempItem;
   }

   public void display() {
     while(true) {
       System.out.println("\t"+ startItem.value);
       if(startItem.next == null) {
         break;
       } else {
         startItem = startItem.next;
       }  
     }
   }   

class Item {
 Integer value;
 Item next;

 Item() {
  this.value = null;
  this.next = null;
 }
}
}
```

The problem is, only the last two additions are getting retained and the previous additions are discarded. This is (of course) because i keep changing the object that the reference startItem points to. My question is, given a recursive structure like this, what is the correct looping mechanism? I know that in a linked list, there is no need to get to the end of the list to perform addition. Linked list structure is used as a context to ask about looping through recursive structures. Thanks.

Comment: You could always look at the source code for `java.util.LinkedList` and see how it was actually implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic structure is correct. You just need to add one line before you start looping...

```
  Item currentItem = startItem;
  while(currentItem.next != null) {
     currentItem = currentItem.next;
  }
```

The only time the field `startItem` should be changed is in your first check if its value is `null`. It's reference should never be changed as it should always point to the start of the structure. Consider making it `final` to enforce this.